# iPyLeaflet: How to set English location names instead of names in local language (Arabic, Mandarin, Korean, etc.)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Goal: I want to map the installed base of an OEM

I use the GoogleMaps - API for geocoding the addresses to longitude, latitude.
For the visualisation I apply iPyleaflet. All that works fine.

However the location names are shown in the local language/letter (e.g. Arabic, Mandarin, Korean, etc.) which makes the map difficult to read for the international community. See picture of Border Vietnam/China:

[image]

Does anybody how to change the map visualization to english location names  ?